# Calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x + \tan(x)}$ with out derivative?

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry

How do I calculate $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{\sin(x)}{x + \tan(x)}$ without derivative?

I cant see the trigonometrical operations that will simply this limit...

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $x$. Use known limits.

Comment: I was thinking about dividing top and bottom by $\sin x$

Comment: @Pedro Both work.

Comment: None of them worked for me.... a end up with t/(t+tan(t))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Divide by $\sin x$ to get $$\frac{1}{\frac{x}{\sin x} + \sec x}$$

Since the limit of $\frac{x}{\sin x}$ is $1$, $\sec(0)$ is $1$, so the limit $= \frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4):

> We can do the following: $$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}{x+\tan x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1+\frac{\tan x}{x}}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1+\frac{\sin x}{x}\cdot{\frac{1}{\cos x}}}=\frac{1}{1+1\cdot 1}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Answer (score 2):

Use
\begin{align*}
\sin x &= x + o(x) \\
\tan x &= x + o(x)
\end{align*}
to get
$$
\frac{\sin x}{x+\tan x} = \frac{x+o(x)}{2x+o(x)} = \frac{1+o(1)}{2+o(1)} \xrightarrow[x\to 0]{}\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: Sorry, but what`s x+o(x)?

Comment: It's a taylor expansion up to order 1, neglecting the terms of degree more than $1$. Equivalently in this case, it is saying $\frac{\sin x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to0]{}1$ (and ditto with $\tan$).

Comment: Is there another way to solve this?

Comment: Yes, if you know this two limits, by dividing both numerator and denominator by $x$. By the way: http://isc.temple.edu/economics/Econ616/Kernel/ast_app.pdf (appendix A2 -- it is in a nutshell what little-oh are, up to a small detail).

Comment: Actually, since you "know" the limit is not $0$ (or guess it), you can prove that $\frac{x+\tan x}{\sin x}$ goes to $2$. Observing that
$$\frac{x+\tan x}{\sin x} = \frac{x}{\sin x} + \frac{1}{\cos x}$$
the second term goes to $1$, and for the first you can use any argument on the behaviour of $\sin x$ near $0$ (eg, directly that the limit of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ being $1$, or whatever.

Comment: This is really just repeating what Luis said in more complicated and probably confusing way for the OP.

Comment: If you are referring to my answer, you would have a point, modulo the fact that it's hard to repeat something which was written later.